# how to get static image from Google maps URL

Tags: google-maps

I have the code to get the static image if I have the proper lat/lng coordinates and it works pretty well.

Here's the problem: I can extract the lat/lng coordinates from standard Google Maps urls, but the shortened URLs give me a trouble. I expand them by opening a connection and *not* following the redirect. Not all of these URLs expand to *stnadard* links:

```
(Usable) https://goo.gl/maps/4Ue1R --> https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bellevue+Community+Church/@43.4662922,-114.2590065,19z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xd7d737a6e26a8d04
(No good) https://goo.gl/maps/jRPuF --> http://maps.google.com/?q=5490+Eglinton+St%2C+Burnaby%2C+BC+V5G&ftid=0x5486770474ff56c9:0x3bcaac9810a24a76&hl=en&gl=us
(No good) https://goo.gl/maps/73TvZ --> http://maps.google.com/?cid=13432210929990533252&hl=en&gl=us
```

Now I'm wondering if there's a way to feed the url to the static maps api and just get the static image for it?